# CORS request in laravel-5.5

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

1. I get 419 unknown status when making a post request via ajax to API.
2. I know this problem is because of the CORS request. I added it on
   client side but do I need to also set request headers , allow-origin
   etc from API also ? if yes how do I include response headers in API
   ?

### NOTE

I have already included all the token stuff according to the docs of laravel-5.5 and internal requests works perfectly.
 
I am using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it.
I defined my api routes in web.php instead of routes/api.php
Everything now works perfect without any errors

Answer (score 0):

Laravel returns a 419 error often when failing CSRF verifications. This sounds like your problem, because you're making a POST request.

Make sure you add the CSRF token to the request. If you're using jQuery you could do something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Make sure you add this to your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta content="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="csrf-token" />
```

**Edit**

I did some research and I'm pretty sure it's the CSRF token which is missing.

The only place where a 419 status code is return in Laravel is here: [`Exceptions/Handler.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L204). If dive a little bit deeper you find that the only place where a `TokenMismatchException` is thrown is at [VerifyCsrfToken](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php#L70). So either the CSRF token is missing or it is wrong.

Comment: I already added it to the forms according to the docs. I think it is CORS issue, I am trying to set headers from client as well as from API. I get following error in console :   "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.localhost' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: I tried using response headers accrording to the docs but it gives same error. Also excluding uri works but it means i need to exclude all the uris and I think it is not a good idea.

Comment: Check your `laravel.log` error log. Maybe you have some errors.

Comment: I checked laravel log and all I figired out is that it throws 419 status because it is a TokenMismatchException, and after research I figured it out that I was on correct path and I need to allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing(CORS) from API, BUT I returned response with HEaders as mentioned in DOCS but not working.